# WebResource.axd Encryption String?

Tags: asp.net, html, webresource

When looking at the source code of a page generated by .ASP (to which I'm a noob,) I sometimes see source referenced through WebResource.axd?d= followed by a really long and unreadable string of letters and numbers. I'll take a guess and say it's a pointer to a script (based on the script tag I see) in a library perhaps?

```
<script src="/Portal/WebResource.axd?d=amy4Qb3YKPApQh4cMI21MoSwRmquuliNIlSx7bF7geaDZ56xwuLIPLkQdH_fNIrpB_hHiKLdv041_WJ1yWe27HSI4a5Spexg3Tg9fHZd33Q1&amp;t=634666000000418502" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Am I close? HOW is this string generated? Is it created automatically by the system? For example, as the developer, if I typed `<script src="/folder/myscript.js">` does WebResource convert it on the server side into this long string and return it this way, for security maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The WebResource.axd is actually an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28VS.100%29.aspx) used to load embedded resources from assemblies. It is the [AssemblyResourceLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.handlers.assemblyresourceloader.aspx) handler, and is defined in the `Config\web.config` file of the framework version you are using. Here's the definition:

```
<add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />
```

See the article [Just Where Is WebResource.axd?](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/10/28/just-where-is-webresource-axd.aspx) for more information. A snippet from the article is below.

> The answer is WebResource.axd. WebResource.axd is an HTTP Handler that
>   is part of the .NET Framework that does one thing and one thing only –
>   it is tasked with getting an embedded resource out of a DLL and
>   returning its content. What DLL to go to and what embedded resource to
>   take are specified through the querystring. For instance, a request to
>   www.yoursite.com/WebResource.axd?d=EqSMS…&t=63421… might return a
>   particular snippet of JavaScript embedded in a particular assembly.
>   The d querystring parameter contains encrypted information that
>   specifies the assembly and resource to return; the t querystring
>   parameter is a timestamp and is used to only allow requests to that
>   resource using that URL for a certain window of time.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand from the links you provided (thank you,) then I AM CLOSE in my understanding. I think I need to create a test .ASP project in VS 2010, with a script or two, and give this a spin. As I mentioned, I'm a noob to .ASP and not sure where to put my Javascripts that WebResource.axd will use. I think I need to study these links a bit more...